# Output a matrix view from table

Tags: php, mysql

I am newbie please help me,
I have data in table with 4 column, something like this :

```
+---------------------+
| id  ah  av  score   |
+---------------------+
| 1   A   A    1      |
| 2   A   B    2      |
| 3   B   A   0.5     |
| 4   B   B   0.14    |
+---------------------+
```

I want to output the query result something like this

```
+-------------------+
| Type   A    B     |
+-------------------+
| A      1    2     |
| B      0.5  0.14  |
+-------------------+
```

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: Any idea how to solve in MySql?

Comment: my current code :
SELECT ah, (CASE WHEN av = 'A' THEN score END) AS A,
(CASE WHEN av = 'B' THEN score END ) AS B
FROM ahp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL pivot row into dynamic number of columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12004603/mysql-pivot-row-into-dynamic-number-of-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT ah type
     , MAX(CASE WHEN av = 'A' THEN score END) 'A'
     , MAX(CASE WHEN av = 'B' THEN score END) 'B' 
  FROM my_table 
 GROUP 
    BY ah;
+------+------+------+
| type | A    | B    |
+------+------+------+
| A    | 1.00 | 2.00 |
| B    | 0.50 | 0.14 |
+------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem requires a pivot table as you are 'pivoting' one of your columns to become a row.

First create a view with all the data you need (pretty much ditch the ID):

```
create view Scores_Simple as (
select
   ah as Type,
   case when av = "A" then Score end as A,
   case when av = "B" then Score end as B
from Scores
);
```

Then pivot the table:

```
create view Scores_Simple_Pivot as (
select
   Type,
   sum(A) as A,
   sum(B) as B
from Scores_Simple
group by Type
);
```

[Tested here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/fd60a/1)

Comment: Thank your for your Answer, If I could vote this up more than once, I would. Great, clear and concise explanation of a common issue that comes up, a solution to which I have rarely seen so well-explained !

Comment: @neraikudai Well, you could always upvote it once. Note that there's no need for a view here.

Comment: @strawberry, thank you for more easier solution.

Comment: @Strawberry yea the view is not needed. Just makes it easier to visualize what is happening in the table, so you can apply this to more complex problems.